# error during writing string to file in python

Tags: python-3.6

```
input1 = input("first input:")
input2 = input("second input:")

file = open("somefile.txt", "w+")
file=file.read()
length=len(file)
print("length")
file.write(input1 + "\n")
file.write(input2 + "\n")
file.close()
```

im constatntly getting an error:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
how to resolve this err

Comment: first input:a
second input:a
length
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "input.py", line 8, in <module>
    file.write(input1 + "\n") #the \n is the line separator (on unix, might be different in windows/mac os)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'.

Answer (score 0):

You reuse `file`.  Once to open the file, and then reassign it as the result of the read, so it becomes a `str`.  Use a different name.